# Neo4j cypher avoid negative values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node that has properties based on another node, For example:

```
MATCH (n:draft {sn:1}),(m:final {sn:1})
SET m.count = m.count - n.count
RETURN m
```

Seems to work. However what I want to do is set `m.count` to 0 if `n.count > m.count`. `n.count > m.count` results in a negative value and I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
MATCH (n:draft {sn:1}),(m:final {sn:1})
SET m.count = CASE WHEN n.count > m.count THEN 0 ELSE m.count - n.count END 
RETURN m
```